# Failed to create component 'ReportViewer'. The error message follows:

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I can't resolve this exception message, please help me.

> Failed to create component `'ReportViewer'`.

The error message follows:

> 'System.InvalidCastException: [A]Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer cannot be cast to [B]Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer.
>   Type A originates from 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\Users\ComputerName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_81430e9d\ProjectAssemblies\tmy4po5j01\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll'.
>   Type B originates from 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' in the context 'LoadFrom' at location 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\SSAS\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll'.
>
> at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewerDesigner.get_ActionLists()
>   at System.ComponentModel.Design.ComponentDesigner.CDDesignerCommandSet.GetCommands(String name)
>   at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerCommandSet.get_ActionLists()
>   at System.Com...'

Comment: Could you please provide more information about what have you done?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, to solve it i had to install the same version of Reporting Services and SQL Server Types packages. Look at the image for versions details.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VBjP.png)

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue problem happened after updating the nuget package. If I build the solution the reports still work. I can't edit them in Visual Studio then I get this error in the designer.